# Write in a jtable over the lines

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Is it possible to do what is in the second row of the table? Write in a jtable over the lines or remove lines of the specific row.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Upload the image to the forum, not to an external site.

Comment: `Write in a jtable over the lines or remove lines of the specific row.` - those are two completely different functions. What is it exactly that you want to do?

Comment: Yes it's possible to write over the table. Use [JLayer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html).

Comment: Camickr I want make a ocupation table, if a room is ocuped the name of client will be writed